# Retrieve year out of text best solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to retrieve de year out of this date (european format date) i know this as a solution but is there a better way to write this code(less code,less declarations etc..)?

You don't need to use those variables. Only variable needed is date = "22/3/2011"

Code in javascript:

```
var myDate = "22/3/2011",
    pos = myDate.lastIndexOf("/"),
    myYear="1970";

myYear = myDate.substr(pos+1);
```

I used jsperf to see which solution was the fastest
http://jsperf.com/retrivetextoutofdate/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
var myDate = "22/3/2011";
yearPart = myDate.split("/")[2];
```

Comment: your solution is the fastest out of the small code you all sugested i'd say you win :p

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDate = "22/3/2011",
    myYear = new Date(myDate).getFullYear();
```

Done.

Comment: Except that it doesn't work unless you swap the `3` and `22`.

Comment: Date of the Year Object = Wed Oct 03 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)
I said its european format so :p

Comment: @pimvdb I guess that would depend on locale settings. Personally when I import a date I use `YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss` format to ensure there's no ambiguity. I also think having the day in the middle of the month and year is just plain stupid... Not little-endian nor big-endian, but both???

Comment: It's not realy stupid because this date is shown to users so they read it like this and i retrieve the date after to filter data from a table with jquery

Comment: Well you said "I also think having the day in the middle of the month and year is just plain stupid..." no offense if i misunderstood something.
And by stupid i meant (bad idea)

Answer (score 0):

```
var year = myDate.match(/\d{4}/);
```